# Why are my DIV's not the same height in Internet explorer?

Tags: css, html

The front page of my site looks perfect (to me) in Safari, and Firefox.  When I look at in in Internet Explorer (7,8,9) the 2 x 2 div's are not equal height.

What am I missing?

My site is here:
https://www.algxchange.com/home

Fixed- I was missing these:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en">
```

Comment: would be easier if you would post some relevant code

Comment: best to see the source of the page

Comment: The divs are of equal height for me. Though there are other problems when you make the page smaller and it wraps extremely poorly due to the explicit heights set on the list items. Also, never use `pt` units other than in a print stylesheet, and the plural form (DIVs, APIs) does not take an apostrophe.

Answer (score 0):

slf's link will be helpful to you.  In essence, IE, in its infinite wisdom, decided to be different from the rest of the browser world, and include any padding and/or border to the width (or height, in this case) specified in the CSS.  So, in every other browser, a box with 70px height and 5px padding on top will be 75px.  In IE, it will be 70px (the box would be 65px, and then the 5px padding).

In a way, it kind of makes sense, but it's irresponsible of Microsoft to stick to it in the face of the W3C spec that says otherwise.